# Properly parsing nested url query parameters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, url-parsing

I am trying to parse the query portion of an URL and retrieve unique query variable names.

```
from urllib.parse import  urlparse, parse_qs
unquoted_url = '?id=test+staging@test.io&p=/#/class/my_finance&e={"name":"asset_download","payload":{"filename":"my_finance.pdf","linkParams":"client=staging&ui=1.5.14&data=1.15.2s"}}&t=1588369315106&pl={"firefox":true,"version":"75.0","versionNumber":75,"mac":true,"desktop":true,"name":"firefox","platform":"mac"}&cb=1587896316419'

parsed = urlparse(unquoted_url)
```

Applying `parse_qs` on `parsed.query+parsed.fragment` yields the following:

```
print(parse_qs(parsed.query + parsed.fragment))

{'id': ['test staging@test.io'],
 'p': ['//class/my_finance'],
 'e': ['{"name":"asset_download","payload":{"filename":"my_finance.pdf","linkParams":"client=staging'],
 'ui': ['1.5.14'],
 'data': ['1.15.2s"}}'],
 't': ['1588369315106'],
 'pl': ['{"firefox":true,"version":"75.0","versionNumber":75,"mac":true,"desktop":true,"name":"firefox","platform":"mac"}'],
 'cb': ['1587896316419']}
```

How do I make the variables `'ui'` and `'data'` as part of `"linkParams"` within the broader `'e'` key in the dictionary? `parse_qs` seems to be split them off based on `'&'` separator.

Comment: Anything after `#` is a fragment and there is no standard parsing.

Comment: @o11c got you. In that case, will removing `#` make that `unquoted_url` string more amenable to standard parsing?

Comment: Are you generating that query string? Or are you getting it from somewhere else? Because looking at it, it appears that the `#` should probably be encoded (that is, it looks like it's part of the value of the `p` parameter).

Comment: @larsks I am getting `unquoted_url` after applying `unquote(unquote(query_string))` to a query string.

Comment: @o11c Looks like even after removing `#`, it does not move the need in solving the problem.

Comment: @gibbz00 my point is that, because there's a `#` in the first place, nobody can have an answer. Go read the documentation of whatever produced this string. Also your `unquote(unquote())` in comments is bogus.

Comment: @o11c original input was encoded double. Hence the `unquote(unquote())` to decode the string to produce `unquoted_url`. Sorry for any miscommunication.